# $.post call to jax-rs not receiving JSON data

Tags: jquery, jax-rs

Unable to read the data in JSON format. I want to receive json object sent in post.

```js
    $.post(url + 'SelfService/login/validate', {key: self.key, value: 
    self.value},function(data, status, xhr) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    },'json');
```

```
@POST
@Path("/validate")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String validate(String data) {
```

Comment: It isn't clear. 1- Do you get into the validate function at all (is Path correct)?  2- If you want validate to get a JSON post request, add @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Comment: It is coming as String even if I do @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
INFO: key=value&key1=value1.

Answer (score 0):

In Jax-RS you can receive a JSON object which maps to a class.

Let's say you post a { "id": 123, "name": "Shahar" }

The simplest approach will be to create a serializable class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class YourClass {

   private Integer id;
   private String name;

   //Must have default constructor
   public YourClass() {
   }

   public YourClass(Integer id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
   }

   public Integer getId() {
     return id;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
     this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
     return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
     this.title = title;
   }
}
```

And define it as an argument in your resource like so:

```
@POST
@Path("/validate")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response validate(YourClass data){
 //interact with data :)
}
```